# Compiling GCC 8.1.0 on Pi64

Tags: pi-3b+, gcc, 64-bit

I have installed Pi64 from [here](https://github.com/Crazyhead90/pi64/releases). I want to compile GCC 8.1.0 as per the instructions [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/07/raspberry-pi-raspbian-compiling-gcc/).

However the text of the article sets the target architecture to `--with-arch=armv6` which is 32bit?

Should/could I change this to `--with-arch=native` or something similar for the ability to compile 64 bit applications or should I use `--with-arch=armv8-a`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that just omitting the gcc parameter `--with-arch` will compile according to your real architecture.